# How to create interface for array of objects in usestate in react js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, tsx

I made a request with AXIOS to the server and then the server returned the value as follows:

[image]

I want to save it in state, here I use react hooks, when I want to set state with data as shown I get error:

```
Argument of type '() => IterableIterator<IMahasiswa>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'IterableIterator<IMahasiswa>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
```

and this is my code:

[image]

and my interface:

[image]

how do I set the interface for `setMahasiswa` I have tried `<IMahasiswa[]>` but it gives the same error, except that in the `res.values` ​​section it is replaced with `res` it is successfully returned, but it will throw another error when I using map for looping

Comment: Can you post the code instead of screenshots?

Comment: Did you actually get the exact same error when using `<IMahasiswa[]>`? Can you include that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that your `axios.get(url[, config])` returns an `any` type by default. So, your `data` there also has `any` type unless you cast it to `IMahasiswa[]`.

However, my suggested solution is to define the type at `axios.get`, here's the outline from their typedef.

```
export interface AxiosInstance {
  //...
  get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<R>;
  //...
}
```

Therefore, you can do something like this;

```
await axiosClient.get<IMahasiswa[]>("asd/asd", {});
```

Here's the full code example;

```
interface IMahasiswa {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const useTest = () => ({
  async fetch(): Promise<IMahasiswa[]> {
    const { data } = await axiosClient.get<IMahasiswa[]>("asd/asd", {});
    return data; // data here has the type of IMahasiswa[]
  },
});

const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:1231",
});

const TestComp = () => {
  const [mahasiswa, setMahasiswa] = React.useState<IMahasiswa[]>([]);
  const testFn = useTest();

  useEffect(() => {
    testFn.fetch().then((res) => {
      setMahasiswa(res);
    });
  }, []);

  return <div>asd</div>;
};
```